# Error:Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, sql, error-handling, terminal, phpmyadmin

[Image of PHP script error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7cbA.png)

Cannot see where the error is occurring.

***servername, user_n, p_word, dbname are all filled out and connection is successful.*

```
<?php
$servername = "";
$user_n = "";
$p_word = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $user_n, $p_word, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{echo nl2br("Failed to connect to MySQL:".mysqli_connect_error()."\n ");}
else
{ echo nl2br("Established Database Connection \n");}

$sanemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
$sanpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);
$sanfname= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['firstName']);
$sanlname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['lastName']);
$sanphone_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['phoneNumber']);
$sanorganization = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['organization']);
$sanjob = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['job']);
$sanwebsite = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['website']);
$sanphone_number_two = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['secondNumber']);
$sanemail_number_two = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['secondEmail']);



//insert query to insert from data into the capstone table
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_info(email, password, fname, lname, phone_number, organization, job, website, phone_number_two, email_number_two)
VALUES('$sanemail', '$sanpassword, '$sanfname', '$sanlname', '$sanphone_number', '$sanorganization, '$sanjob', '$sanwebsite', '$sanphone_number_two', '$sanemail_number_two')";

//check for error on insert 
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{ die('Error:' .mysqli_error($con));}

echo "1 record added";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

[Image of database values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMypc.png)

Comment: You might wanna add your error as text; it makes it easier for us to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on the line where you create the `$sql` variable:

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO user_info(
        email,
        password,
        fname,
        lname,
        phone_number,
        organization,
        job,
        website,
        phone_number_two,
        email_number_two
    ) VALUES (
        '$sanemail',
        '$sanpassword, -- HERE
        '$sanfname',
        '$sanlname',
        '$sanphone_number',
        '$sanorganization, -- AND HERE
        '$sanjob',
        '$sanwebsite',
        '$sanphone_number_two',
        '$sanemail_number_two'
    )";
```

These two lines:

```
'$sanpassword,
'$sanorganization,
```

They are missing closing quotes.

Comment: Thank you soo much for the timely response, I figured it was a syntax error somewhere I just needed an extra set of eyes on it!